# Length of visible option elements always shows `0`

Tags: jquery, html-select

I only want to know the `length` of visible `option` elements.

Same value for all elements is **must have**.

The following code always shows `0`.

Please help.

```js
$('select option[data-id=2]').hide();
var exist = $('select option[value=1]:visible').length;
alert(exist);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value='1'>test 1</option>
  <option value='1' data-id='2'>test 2</option>
</select>
```

Screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: `alert()` shows 1 to you? This is impossible, I just tried it from different browsers and computers.

Comment: "All option elements are considered hidden, regardless of their selected state." - https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Comment: i am also getting alert 1.

Comment: Check out screen shot. How are you guys getting `1`?? =))))

Comment: I get 0. Notice that it shows 0 even if you don't `hide()` them.

Comment: Any idea how the other two users are getting 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$('select option[data-id=2]').hide();

var length = $('select option[value=1]').filter(function() {
     return $(this).css('display') != 'none';
}).length;

alert(length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value='1'>test 1</option>
  
  <option value='1' data-id='2'>test 2</option>
</select>
```

Try this way of checking. Filter it then check if display block then do the length counting

Comment: FYI, on my browser (Safari/Mac) the option is not actually hidden (but the alert says 1).

Comment: but in chrome it hides the second option and will count 0.. this way it will check for display block and count it

Comment: Works great, but still confused about different users reporting different results... I tested on Mac/Safari, IE, Chrome, getting consistent results.

Comment: @guradio: no comments about Ghasan's and vijayP comments? =) just ignored?

Comment: @AlexG im getting 0 as well when i try your snippet but when i use safari the secont option is not hidden maybe they are using safari

Answer (score 1):

I am getting 1 when I run it in Firefox, but 0 when I run it in Chrome.

It seems that the issue arises from Chrome running the code before displaying the whole select element, where Firefox run the code after displaying the select element.

The following displays 2 followed by 0 in Firefox, whereas it displays 0 followed by 2 in Chrome.

```js
var exist = $('option:visible').length;
alert(exist);
exist = $('option:hidden').length;
alert(exist);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value='1'>test 1</option>
  <option value='1' data-id='2'>test 2</option>
</select>
```

The solution that guradio stated works because you are checking whether or not the option has this property `display`, and for the visible one, it is not defined, and thus not `none`, so the condition is true.

However, your code was asking asking jQuery if this element is actually visible, regardless of the display property.

I am not sure why Chrome behaves this way really, and the issue persists even if I put the code in a standalone html page.

Edit:

It seems as Owen pointed out a non-defined behavior between different browsers, even though jQuery [states clearly](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) that all options are considered hidden regardless of display property, as we can see from the behavior of Firefox.

In conclusion, you would better stick with setting and checking the `display` property for what you want, and use other selectors such as `:selected` and `:not(:selected)` for the negation.

Comment: I don't think it is a timing issue. Try putting the code in a `setTimeout` callback to confirm. Safari acts the same way even if you wait.

Comment: @Owen I think you are right. It is just intriguing why browsers behave differently.